# Paste text from excelrow in row above

Tags: excel

I'm having an excel issue for which I can't seem to find an efficient solution. Excel-file looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is past the text from rows that don't begin with 2023 or 2022 after the text on the previous line. So in this example, the text from row 2 should be pasted after the the text from row 1.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Use VBA or write conditional formula in another cells/sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input (column A, no header, sheet "Sheet1"):**

| A |
| --- |
| 2023 |
| a |
| b |
| 2022 |
| 2022 |
| 2023 |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| 2022 |
| a |
| 2022 |

**Code:**

```vb
Sub merge()
    Dim rng As Range, arr() As Variant, resultArr() As Variant, separator As String
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A13")
    arr = rng
    ReDim resultArr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    
    separator = ", "
    
    Dim writeRow As Long, testValue As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        testValue = Left(arr(i, 1), 4)
        If testValue = "2022" Or testValue = "2023" Then
            writeRow = writeRow + 1
            resultArr(writeRow, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        Else
            resultArr(writeRow, 1) = resultArr(writeRow, 1) & separator & arr(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    rng = resultArr
    
End Sub
```

**Output (the original data is overwritten, let me know if this is not desired behavior):**

| A |
| --- |
| 2023, a, b |
| 2022 |
| 2022 |
| 2023, a, b, c, d |
| 2022, a |
| 2022 |

In case you wanted this to behave differently from how it does now, please ask.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the line "resultArr(writeRow, 1) = resultArr(writeRow, 1) & separator & arr(i, 1)". Saying the subscript is out of range. My A-column has 17017 rows, but I changed that accordingly.

Comment: @Octavarium I tested it and the only way I was able to get it to crash is when the first cell in the data didn't start with 2022 or 2023. Is this the case with your data? If it is, what do you want to do with the cells that are above the first cell which starts with the years?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. The file is derived from a csv which has headers. I'll try it by removing the first row.